# Check if the server side processing is done

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, networking

I have an unity app that needs to make a webrequest. There is a html page (which is not under my control, otherwise I'd have done it differently) which, when opened does some server side processing that may take from 10~15 seconds to load. I want to recheck every 10 seconds for the word "Done" as it indicates the result is ready.

Here's my concept code:

```
IEnumerator MakeData()
{
    using (UnityWebRequest www1 = UnityWebRequest.Get(link))
    {
        yield return www1.Send();
        if (www1.isNetworkError || www1.isHttpError)
        {
            Debug.Log(www1.error);
        }
        else
        {
            string tt = "working";
            while (tt.Contains("working"))
            {
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(10);
                //how do I get new updated html?
                tt = html_after_10_seconds;
            }
            if (tt.Contains("Done")) { Process(tt); }
        }
        www1.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Few things:

Currently it gets the page while it is working. Process function can extract the text I want from the html, once it is ready. I have a good reason to use it this way. Also, it is an extremely niche thing, so very unlikely many people will make this webrequest at the same time.

Sorry for bothering! Have a great day!

Comment: I don't think this will do what you expect .. once the web request is done and has downloaded the html content ... it will not be aware of any further changes made by the server afterwards .. the web request doesn't executed JavaScript etc ... It also doesn't handle forwarding to another page ...

Comment: @derHugo so I can't do it or do I have to use some other library to do it?

Comment: @atulpurna If you want a live feed between a server and your Unity game, you can try [Websockets](https://github.com/sta/websocket-sharp). Think of web sockets as a continuous flow of data between a host and client once a connection is established. It might be overkill for your use case though.

Comment: why are you checking every 10 seconds?

Comment: @TEEBQNE OP states though that the server side is not under his control so if the server doesn't provide a WebSocket this can't be used

Comment: @derHugo True had overlooked that, my bad!

Comment: @TEEBQNE so, I can't do it?

Comment: I am going to try to use an Unity Webview and keep the panel/gameobject transparency to 0